# Getting Resource id #26 PHP Error

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting the error "Resource id #26" in PHP:

```
$R = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Replies WHERE tid='$gS->ID' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT     1"); 
?>

    <tr style="<? echo "$scss"; ?>">
    <td width="560" class="thread" colspan="4" height="70" style="" border-left: 1px solid gainsboro;text-align: center;"><center><a href="./Post.php?id="><? echo "$gS->Title";     ?></center></a>
    <td width="100" align="center" class="thread" style="text-align: center;" valign="middle"><? echo "$R"; ?></td>
    <td width="100" align="center" class="thread" valign="middle"></td>
    <td width="200" class="thread" style="border-right: 1px solid gainsboro;">by <? echo "$LastReply"; ?> <br>January, 1st, 2000 - 2:00am</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/mysql_query) doesn't return any values. You still need to `_fetch_xy()` them.

Comment: You're echoing out your recordset. You'll probably want to `mysql_fetch_array()` or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need fetch the query result like this

```
$R = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Replies WHERE tid='$gS->ID' ORDER BY ID DESC LIMIT     1");
```

since `$R` is just one result you don't need to use a `while`. use [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)

```
 $row=  mysql_fetch_assoc($R);
```

to print use

```
<?php echo $row['FieldName'];?>
```

Try to update to mysqli or PDO

[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: It just gives a blank result.